# php result to json object

Tags: php, json

I am having a database table named "updates" which contains fields "id" and "post" which are of type 'int' and 'text' respectively. Now I am retrieving all posts as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT post FROM updates");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$postsarray[] = $row;
}
```

Now I want to convert this array into JSON array as follows:

```
{
    "posts":[{
            "post1",
            "post2",
            ..
            }]
}
```

I have tried many ways but could not get that.
Can anyone help me doing that?

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)($postsarray);

Comment: that is giving me :"   [["post1"],["post2"]] ".. @caCtus

Comment: I am not sure the result you want (the one you show in your question) is Json.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. `{` starts an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT post FROM updates");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $postsarray[] = $row[0];
}
$arr = array();
$arr['posts'] = $postsarray;
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

`mysqli_fetch_row` itself returns an array (the row), so you have to get the first element when adding into the `$postsarray`.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `json_encode` function translates the data passed to it to a JSON string which can then be output to a JavaScript variable. We demonstrate on this page with single level arrays. Other pages demonstrate using `json_encode` with multi-dimensional arrays and scalar values.

The PHP `json_encode` function returns a string containing the JSON equivalent of the value passed to it as we demonstrate here with a numerically indexed array:

```
<?php
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');
echo json_encode($ar); // ["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"]
?>
```